# How to get a country place ID for an associated locality place ID?

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I have a "locality" type `place_id` (e.g. `ChIJT-bVPNJAh0gRzCSbulDuSWs`) (that I got by querying location [`5.768757,-2.004222`](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=55.768757%2C-2.004222&result_type=locality)).

I want to get the associated "country" type `place_id`.

I have tried looking up the same location but with `result_type=country`. However, that gives zero results.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=53.352118%2C-6.393696&result_type=country

> This (53.352118, -6.393696) location now started to return results for `result_type=country`. This however, does not solve the underlying issue – that this data is not always available.
>
> As an example, lookup (53.177459,-6.797582). Here is the [request & result for the query at the time of this writing](https://gist.github.com/gajus/e12fcd953f153f4b9f38b84ea65ad514#file-countrylookup-sh-L63-L67).

I have also tried using the coordinates obtained from `locality.geometry.location.<lat|lng>`. This sometimes works and sometimes doesn't work. Here is an example of when it doesn't work:

- [locality query](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=52.587356%2C-2.123218&result_type=locality)
- [country query](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=52.586973%2C-2.12882&result_type=country)

Is there a reliable way to get "country" type `place_id` using "locality" type `place_id`?

Comment: When I execute https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=53.352118%2C-6.393696&result_type=country&key=MY_KEY I get a result with place ID ChIJ-ydAXOS6WUgRCPTbzjQSfM8 (Ireland). Do you apply an API key in your request? What is the response?

Comment: @xomena It looks like Google fixed (or whatever caching layer remediated itself) this particular data point. As an example of the issue, refer to [53.177459,-6.797582](https://gist.github.com/gajus/e12fcd953f153f4b9f38b84ea65ad514#file-countrylookup-sh-L63-L67).

Comment: You are right. Seems to be a bug, try to file it in the [public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/). Anyway, you already know the place ID for Ireland ChIJ-ydAXOS6WUgRCPTbzjQSfM8. I don't think that Google has several instances for the country.

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#place_id%3DChIJ-ydAXOS6WUgRCPTbzjQSfM8

Comment: But I don't know whether what [location query result](https://gist.github.com/gajus/e12fcd953f153f4b9f38b84ea65ad514#file-countrylookup-sh-L23-L27) describes as a `"long_name" : "Ireland", "short_name" : "IE"` is the same what my database contains as Ireland with ID `ChIJ-ydAXOS6WUgRCPTbzjQSfM8`. It is a reasonable assumption (there aren't countries with the same names), but not an assumption that I'd like to use to build relations in a database.

Comment: Raised an issue, https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10826&thanks=10826&ts=1478526961.

Comment: The country code ("short_name") in a result is the ISO country code, so it is just as unique as the Place ID of its country, i.e. there are no 2 countries with the same short name, no duplicate countries, etc.